# How can I calculate sample size for case control study?"

Tags: probability, statistical-significance, sampling, sample-size, population

Please, I want to understand how to calculate the sample size the formula for the project entiled, "Evaluation of renal function in type2 diabetes mellitus patients attending federal medical Like"

Comment: What test do you want to do? (One or two sample? What significance level?) What size change in renal function do you need to detect? What power do you require? (That is, what probability of detecting a difference of specified size?) What is the approximate SD of such renal function data? // At least approximate answers to all these questions are required in order to get a recommended sample size.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you will do a one-sample test of $H_0: \mu = \mu_0$ against $H_a: \mu\ne\mu_0$ at level $\alpha = 0.05 = 5\%.$

Data are normally distributed with $\sigma \approx 10.$

You wish to detect a change from $\mu_0$ as large as $\mu_0 \pm \sigma$
with power $90\%.$

Here is output from Minitab's 'power and sample size' procedure. I used
$\sigma = 10$ and supposed you wanted to detect differences of
size $10, 15,$ or $20.$

```
Power and Sample Size 

1-Sample t Test

Testing mean = null (versus ≠ null)
Calculating power for mean = null + difference
α = 0.05  Assumed standard deviation = 10


             Sample  Target
 Difference    Size   Power  Actual Power
         10      13     0.9      0.910708
         15       7     0.9      0.907663
         20       5     0.9      0.908885
```

[image]

For answers less than $n = 30,$ it is necessary to use
a noncentral t distribution. For approximate answers when
$n > 30,$ the formula is
$$n \approx \frac{\sigma^2}{\Delta^2}(1.96 + 1.28)^2,$$
where $\Delta$ is the difference to detect, 1.96 cuts
probability 0.025 from the upper tail of a standard normal
distribution and 1.28 cuts probability 0.1 from the upper
tail of a standard normal distribution.